# Image Captured in Landscape mode rotating in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape

I am presenting `UIImagePickerController` in Portrait mode with camera. I am capturing the image in Landscape mode. The `UIImagePickerController` is auto-rotating the captured image by 90 degrees. Why does this do so? How can I keep the original captured image?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:oldImage.CGImage scale:oldImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```